# The modulus of each columns of the rotation matrix is

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, matrix

The modulus of each columns of the rotation matrix is

1, 0.5, 0.866 or 1.366

which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The modulus of each column vector is 1. The column vectors of a rotation matrix are expected to be orthonormal.